# Highcharts. Indentation and formatting issues

Tags: highcharts

[image]

I want to make the graph start at 0 (as shown in the picture) and have the string formatted according to the regular expression `replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, " ")` but all my attempts are unsuccessful.

```js
chartOptions: {
        colors: ['#3DC3FB', '#FF5252', '#D2F449', '#179877'],
        title: {
          text: "",
        },
        credits: {
          enabled: false
        },
        tooltip: {
          formatter: function () {
            if (this.x > 0) {
              return this.x;
            } else return false;
          },
        },
        plotOptions: {
          series: {
            enableMouseTracking: false,
            states: {
              hover: {
                enabled: false
              },
              normal: {
                animation: false
              },
              select: {
                enabled: false
              }
            }
          },
        },
        xAxis: {
          gridLineWidth: 1,
          tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
          lineColor: "#A4A4A4",
          min: 0,
          categories: [null, "10 лет"],
          top: 10,
          right: -100,
          title: {
            style: {
              color: "#A4A4A4"
            }
          },
        },
        yAxis: {
          gridLineWidth: 0,
          tickColor: 'undefined',
          tickLength: 5,
          tickWidth: 1,
          tickPosition: 'outside',
          lineWidth: 1,
          lineColor: '#A4A4A4',
          min: 3,
          title: {
            text: "Доход от инвестиций",
            margin: 10,
            align: "low",
            style: {
              color: "#A4A4A4"
            },
            y: -50,
          },
          labels: {
            enabled: false,
          },
        },
        legend: {enabled: false},
        marker: {
          enabled: false,
          symbol: 'circle',
          radius: 12,
          states: {
            hover: {
              fillColor: 'white',
              lineColor: 'green',
              lineWidth: 0
            }
          }
        },
        series: [
          {
            type: 'line',
            name: "ВДело",
            data: [0, 1100],
            dataLabels: {
              x: -100,
              y: 5,
              enabled: true,
              // useHTML: true,
              format: `{point.y}/мес`,
              formatter: function () {
                return Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y,2);
              },
              color: "#3DC3FB",
              style:{
                fontSize: 20,
                lineHeight: 18,
                fontWeight: 500,
                fontFamily: 'Gilroy',
                fontStyle: 'normal',
              }
            },
            animation: {
              defer: 1
            },
            marker: {
              symbol: 'circle',
              radius: 4,
              states: {
                hover: {
                  fillColor: '#3DC3FB',
                  lineColor: 'green',
                  lineWidth: 0
                }
              }
            },

          },
          {
            type: 'line',
            name: "Акции",
            data: [0, 550],
            animation: {
              defer: 1
            },
            marker: {
              symbol: 'circle',
              radius: 4,
              states: {
                hover: {
                  fillColor: '#FF5252',
                  lineColor: 'green',
                  lineWidth: 0
                }
              }
            },
          },
          {
            type: 'line',
            name: "Облигации",
            data: [0, 366],
            animation: {
              defer: 1
            },
            marker: {
              symbol: 'circle',
              radius: 4,
              states: {
                hover: {
                  fillColor: '#D2F449',
                  lineColor: 'green',
                  lineWidth: 0
                }
              }
            },
          },
          {
            type: 'line',
            name: "Депозит",
            data: [0, 275],
            animation: {
              defer: 1
            },
            marker: {
              symbol: 'circle',
              radius: 4,
              states: {
                hover: {
                  fillColor: '#179877',
                  lineColor: 'green',
                  lineWidth: 0
                }
              }
            },
          },
        ],
      },
```

I am new to highcharts and have a hard time with huge documentation. help me please

Answer (score 0):

Understood the cost of his sleep. For those who will be interested. So that the graph starts like in the picture.

```js
plotOptions: {
          series: {
            findNearestPointBy: 'x',
            label: {
              connectorAllowed: false
            },
            pointPlacement: 'on'
          }
        }
```

and

```js
          {
            type: 'line',
            name: "ВДело",
            data: [0, 1100],
            dataLabels: {
              x: -50,
              y: -10,
              enabled: true,
              format: `{point.y}/мес`,
              pointFormat: ' <b>{point.y:,.0f}/мес</b>',
              shared: true,
              color: "#3DC3FB",
              style:{
                fontSize: 20,
                lineHeight: 18,
                fontWeight: 500,
                fontFamily: 'Gilroy',
                fontStyle: 'normal',
              }
            },
```

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to the place to start the chart in the category axis, you need to only change `xAxis.min` to `0.5`

**Sample code:**

```
  xAxis: {
    min: 0.5,
    tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
    type: 'category'
  },
```

**Simplified demo:**

https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/jt1gqrnb/